# my app doesn't show anything on Tablet

Tags: android, responsive-design, tablet

My app works perfect on mobile but when i try to run it on tablet it doesn't show anything or any errors ,I'm Running it on Genymotion Emulator (Google Nexus 9) .
i will post my Log, code and Xml_layouts here .

this also appears in my Event Log

```
12:17:25 PM Can't bind to local 8636 for debugger
12:17:28 PM An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
        java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

Manifiest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
    >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DetailedActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_detailed"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        >
    </activity>
</application>
```

Log

```
12-30 04:04:32.022 624-1069/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.example.ahmed.popularmovies/.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10039 on display 0
12-30 04:04:32.023 624-693/system_process W/AudioTrack: AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
12-30 04:04:32.122 624-1069/system_process V/WindowManager: addAppToken: AppWindowToken{f0d2b97 token=Token{25cc7616 ActivityRecord{206e6f31 u0 com.example.ahmed.popularmovies/.MainActivity t14}}} to stack=1 task=14 at 0
12-30 04:04:32.177 624-648/system_process V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{25431ee u0 Starting com.example.ahmed.popularmovies} at 3 of 8 (after Window{2b77accb u0 com.android.music/com.android.music.ArtistAlbumBrowserActivity})
12-30 04:04:32.495 10401-10401/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-30 04:04:32.502 624-1060/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 10401:com.example.ahmed.popularmovies/u0a60 for activity com.example.ahmed.popularmovies/.MainActivity
12-30 04:04:33.754 69-69/? D/: Socket deconnection
12-30 04:04:33.913 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-30 04:04:33.951 10401-10401/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf3e34a00, tid 10401
12-30 04:04:33.976 10401-10401/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-30 04:04:33.995 624-11052/system_process V/WindowManager: Adding window Window{30fa2887 u0 com.example.ahmed.popularmovies/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.MainActivity} at 3 of 9 (before Window{25431ee u0 Starting com.example.ahmed.popularmovies})
12-30 04:04:34.191 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
12-30 04:04:34.198 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
12-30 04:04:34.258 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
12-30 04:04:34.310 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf3e34b60, tid 10418
12-30 04:04:34.457 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-30 04:04:35.630 624-706/system_process D/TaskPersister: removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=12_task.xml
12-30 04:04:35.631 624-706/system_process D/TaskPersister: removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=12_task_thumbnail.png
12-30 04:04:35.762 69-69/? D/: Socket deconnection
12-30 04:04:36.060 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
12-30 04:04:36.282 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-30 04:04:36.282 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3ee9680, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-30 04:04:36.567 10401-10401/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies I/Choreographer: Skipped 153 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-30 04:04:36.741 10401-10418/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies V/RenderScript: 0xf3da0c00 Launching thread(s), CPUs 2
12-30 04:04:36.976 624-648/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed com.example.ahmed.popularmovies/.MainActivity: +4s669ms
12-30 04:04:37.178 10401-10401/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies V/debug: com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.movieAdapter@c9cb5d4
12-30 04:04:37.288 10401-10401/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
12-30 04:04:37.568 10401-10401/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies W/InputMethodManager: Ignoring onBind: cur seq=26, given seq=25
12-30 04:04:37.673 10401-10409/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies W/art: Suspending all threads took: 5.839ms
12-30 04:04:37.699 10401-10414/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5221(317KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(143KB) LOS objects, 30% free, 1361KB/1954KB, paused 7.964ms total 124.405ms
12-30 04:04:37.774 69-69/? D/: Socket deconnection
12-30 04:04:39.770 69-69/? D/: Socket deconnection
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String popluar = "popularity.desc";
public static final String top_rate = "vote_average.desc";
public static Context context;
public static ArrayList<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
public static FragmentManager fm;
public static Configuration config;


public static String id;
public static String title;
public static String releaseDate;
public static String overView;
public static String voteAverage;
public static String popularity;
public static String poster;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    context = MainActivity.this;
    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    config = getResources().getConfiguration();

    ReplaceFragments(popluar);


}

public static boolean isTablet() {
    if (config.smallestScreenWidthDp >= 600) {
        return true;
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.most_popular) {
        ReplaceFragments(popluar);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.highest_rated) {
        ReplaceFragments(top_rate);
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.favorite) {
        ReplaceFragments("fav");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void ReplaceFragments(String SortBy) {
    if (isTablet()){
        MainFragment mainFragment = MainFragment.newInstance(SortBy);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tabletMain, mainFragment)
                .commit();
    }else{
        MainFragment mainFragment = MainFragment.newInstance(SortBy);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentMain, mainFragment)
                .commit();
    }

}

public static void showDetails(int position) {
    id = movies.get(position).getId();
    title = movies.get(position).getTitle();
    releaseDate = movies.get(position).getReleaseDate();
    overView = movies.get(position).getOverView();
    voteAverage = movies.get(position).getVoteAverage();
    popularity = movies.get(position).getPopularity();
    poster = movies.get(position).getLargePoster();

    if (isTablet()) {
        DetailFragment detailFragment = new DetailFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tabletDetail, detailFragment)
                .commit();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailedActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

}

}
```

MainFragment

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

public final static String API_KEY = "b932ba435fc93a5944938fe9d44cd198";
public final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=&api_key=";

movieAdapter adapter;
movieAdapter DbAdapter;
GridView gridview;
DbOpenHelper dbOpenHelper;
Context context;
String sortOrder;


public MainFragment() {
}

public static MainFragment newInstance(String sortOrder) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("SORT", sortOrder);
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        sortOrder = getArguments().getString("SORT");
        if (sortOrder == "fav") {
            new FetchDataFromDb().execute();
        } else {
            new FetchDataFromApi(sortOrder).execute();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    context = getActivity();
    adapter = new movieAdapter(context, R.layout.movie_item, MainActivity.movies);
    return view;
}

class FetchDataFromApi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    String SORT_CATEGORY;

    FetchDataFromApi(String paramUrl) {
        SORT_CATEGORY = paramUrl;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            Uri uriBuilder = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("sort_by", SORT_CATEGORY)
                    .appendQueryParameter("api_key", API_KEY)
                    .build();
            URL url = new URL(uriBuilder.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            String response = sb.toString();
            ParseJsonData(response);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        Log.v("debug", String.valueOf(gridview.getAdapter()));
        if (MainActivity.isTablet()) {
            /*MainActivity.showDetails(0);*/
        }
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long ss) {
                MainActivity.showDetails(position);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void ParseJsonData(String response) throws JSONException {
    String PosterBaseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
    String LargePoster = "w185";
    String SmallPoster = "";
    final String RESULTS = "results";
    final String ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";
    final String OVERVIEW = "overview";
    final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
    final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
    final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
    final String POPULARITY = "popularity";
    final String ID = "id";

    MainActivity.movies.clear();

    JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
   // Log.v("Json", response);
    JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray(RESULTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String id = object.getString(ID);
        String title = object.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);
        String releaseDate = object.getString(RELEASE_DATE);
        String overView = object.getString(OVERVIEW);
        String voteAverage = object.getString(VOTE_AVERAGE);
        String popularity = object.getString(POPULARITY);
        String posterPath = object.getString(POSTER_PATH);
        String BigPoster = PosterBaseUrl + LargePoster + posterPath;
        String MinPoster = PosterBaseUrl + SmallPoster + posterPath;

        Movie m = new Movie();
        m.setId(id);
        m.setTitle(title);
        m.setReleaseDate(releaseDate);
        m.setOverView(overView);
        m.setVoteAverage(voteAverage);
        m.setPopularity(popularity);
        m.setLargePoster(BigPoster);
        m.setMinPoster(MinPoster);
        MainActivity.movies.add(m);
    }
}

class FetchDataFromDb extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        dbOpenHelper = new DbOpenHelper(MainActivity.context);
        MainActivity.movies = dbOpenHelper.getAllFavoritePosters();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        Log.v("database status", "Finished From Db");
        DbAdapter = new movieAdapter(context, R.layout.movie_item, MainActivity.movies);
        gridview.setAdapter(DbAdapter);
        if (MainActivity.isTablet()) {
            MainActivity.showDetails(0);
        }
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long ss) {
                MainActivity.showDetails(position);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `it doesn't show anything` means what? activity is not running? View is not coming?! Paste your `android manifest`.

Comment: `<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>`

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar This is my MainActivity Decleration maybe the problem is bcuz of ConfgChanges "screenSize" shall i remove it ?

Comment: In android studio for your activity xml in design tab choose virtual device such as nexus 10 or nexus 12 etc and then try whether your views are showing or not.

Comment: Try removing `screenSize` from your Manifest. Also check that you are not limiting the compatible screens. It would be great if you included your Manifest in your question.

Comment: it doesn't neither in mobile cuz i'm adding the fragment in activity layout in a from of FrameLayout so views doesn't appear in design tab

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i added the manifiest to te question what do u mean by not limiting the compatible screens ?!

Comment: In the Manifest it is possible to limit the compatibility to certain screens only. It's not your case. But I'd try to remove `screenSize`, which could be an issue.

Comment: i removed **screenSize** from manifiest and nothing happened i wonder why it says " The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" in the log although my http connections are in asyncTasks and they work perfect for mobile !